# Rails + Paperclip - Update/Edit multiple images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

I'm building a Rails app to store products, so a product has_many images. I can upload up to 4 images when I create a New record, this is the *New Action* in Products controller:

```
def new
    @product = Product.new
    4.times { @product.images.build }
end
```

And this is the view:

```
<%= form_for @product, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    .
    .
    .
    .    
    <%= f.fields_for :images do |builder| %>

        <% if builder.object.new_record? %>
        <p>
            <%= builder.label :image, "Image File" %>
            <%= builder.file_field :image %>
        </p>

        <% end %>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And in the Product's model I allowed nested attributes:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['image'].nil? }
```

Everything is fine up to this point. My question is: How can I update the images that belongs to the product? For example: If the user creates a new record with 2 or 3 images, then the user should be able to edit the product description and its images. So far my Edit action is defined this way:

```
def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update(product_params)
       redirect_to :root
    else
       render 'edit'
    end
end
```

I'm using Paperclip to upload images. I tried doing the same thing I did the the *New Action*, but instead of updating the images, it just uploaded new ones.

EDIT:

product_params:

```
  def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :info_item, :description, :price, :subcategory_id, :category_id, :images_attributes => [:image])
 end
```

Comment: Are you using the same `form` for updating? And also please post `product_params` in the question

Comment: Hi @Pavan, yes I am using the same form structure for updating, the product's description updates fine, but I can't get to update the images, it just creates a new record in the images' model. I edited my post to add product_params.

Comment: Try adding `:id` to `product_params` like `params.require(:product).permit(:title, :info_item, :description, :price, :subcategory_id, :category_id, :images_attributes => [:id, :image])`

Comment: @Pavan, thank you for your reply, I did what you said and still no luck. This screenshot shows a sample app I built for testing, when I click on Edit to edit some product it retrieves all its description except for the Images that belongs to that product. If I select an Image, instead of updating the existing images it just save a new record. This is the screenshot's URL: http://i.imgur.com/HRuhxrp.png