# display a paperclip image using Foreign key association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, paperclip

I have two Models. I would like to use the foreign key(resource_id) in my resources_game model to display an image.

This is my `Resource` Model

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :resource_books
has_many :resource_games, :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to :resouce_type
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "100x120>"},
                  :url  => "/assets/games/images/:basename/:style/:basename.:extension",
                  :path =>":rails_root/public/assets/games/images/:basename/:style/:basename.:extension"
accepts_nested_attributes_for :resource_books, :resource_games
```

This is my `ResourceGame` Model

```
class ResourceGame < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :resource, :class_name => ResourceGame, :foreign_key => :resource_id
attr_accessor :add_resources

has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "100x120>"},
                  :url  => "/assets/games/images/:basename/:style/:basename.:extension",
                  :path =>":rails_root/public/assets/games/images/:basename/:style/:basename.:extension"

accepts_nested_attributes_for :add_resource
```

If the image was stored in the resources table I would retrieve and populate the table like this:

in my `Resources` Controller:

```
@latest_resources = Resource.paginate(:page => params[:page],:order => "id DESC", :per_page => 10)
```

then in my view:

```
<% @latest_resources.each do |project| %>

   <tr>
     <td><%= image_tag project.image.url(:small)  %></td>
     <td><%= project.resouce_type_name %></td>
     <td><%= project.name %></td>
     <td><%= project.url %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

The image is being stored in the `resources_game` table, so what should I do to write in the `image_tag` in my view to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me by including the resource_games model to the array in the controller .

```
    @latest_resources = Resource.find(:all, :include => :resource_games)
```

and calling in the View like this:

```
<% @latest_resources.each do |project| %>      
  <tr>
  <% project.resource_games.each do |resourcegames| %>      

<td><%= image_tag resourcegames.image.url(:small)  %></td>
  <% end %>
<td><%= project.resouce_type_name %></td>
```

This way I'm populating a table with data from multiples tables at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `form_for` and build a nested form. Here are the [instructions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms), go over it and then ping me.

`@resource.resourcegames`  is an array because you have an `has_many` relationship, so when you use `form_for` you can either have 1 nested form or many nested forms.

Also I quote the [paperclip github page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#usage)

> ## Usage
>
> The basics of Paperclip are quite simple: Declare that your model has an attachment with the has_attached_file method, and give it a name.
>
> Paperclip will wrap up to four attributes (all prefixed with that attachment's name, so you can have multiple attachments per model if you wish) and give them a friendly front end. These attributes are:

```
<attachment>_file_name
<attachment>_file_size
<attachment>_content_type
<attachment>_updated_at
```

> By default, only _file_name is required for Paperclip to operate. You'll need to add _content_type in case you want to use content type validation.
>
> More information about the options passed to has_attached_file is available in the documentation of Paperclip::ClassMethods.

There are several guides at the following links

http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails/

[Rails + Paperclip - Update/Edit multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441057/rails-paperclip-update-edit-multiple-images)

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1734

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/Waxw8D6seRc

https://sleekd.com/general/adding-multiple-images-to-a-rails-model-with-paperclip/

Comment: Hi im new to rails, i dont see how a form is gonna help me here..im trying to display data not collect it. Can you elaborate? i know how to created nested form btw, but im not sure what to do next...

Comment: @Andy87 ok, but I need you to explain me what is `AddResource` in the following query `@latest_resources = AddResource.paginate(:page => params[:page],:order => "id DESC", :per_page => 10)` thanks

Comment: This is just an array of the last 10 created reasources...that "addresouce" is in fact the resource model. (because i renamed it and when i wrote i forgot) so in fact that code is  the same as : latest_resources = resource.find(:all, :order => "id desc", :limit => 10).reverse

Comment: @Andy87 your question is not clear.. update it and make it very clear, because there are many questions to answer in the community

Comment: @Andy87 if you want to make a question on StackOverflow you need to 1) Ask yourself what you want to do 2) Find what you can not do 3) put down a simple code example of your issue 4) try to solve that code example 5) post the question 6) update it and include additional explanation. In your question you are just posting your issue, which is very confusing ... also you do not put a clear question, we are here to help you, there is no obligation to solve your problems, you should do that alone